# FlashBuilder Theme default.css

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I have created a Flex Library project to be used as a custom theme. All of my skins and a default.css have been built out and a theme.swc file is compiled.

In my application I can include the default css in the  and that seems to work, but how do you create the SWC that can be installed in to Flex and applied as a theme and automatically use the included default.css that's compiled into the swc with out using the  declaration?

I'm using the latest version of FlashBuilder.

Comment: so If i want to import the theme into FlashBuilder I can use the -include-file default.css default.css argument but this doesn't seem to work when trying to just use the theme.swc